# Count words from a string and call it from a method?

Tags: java

This is the code I have so far below and what I would like to do is to call the method that I created to show the user how many words are in the user input. I'm not sure if what i'm calling is wrong or what but if I could get some help from somebody who knows what they're doing.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Chapter3Question5 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Type some words: ");
        String s = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("There are " + (countWords) + " words.");
        //want to call the method here and print the results

        in.close();
    }

    public static int countWords(String str) {
        int wordCount = 0;

        boolean word = false;
        int endLine = str.length() - 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {

            if (Character.isLetter(str.charAt(i)) && i != endLine) {
                word = true;
            } else if (!Character.isLetter(str.charAt(i)) && word) {
                wordCount++;
                word = false;
            } else if (Character.isLetter(str.charAt(i)) && i == endLine) {
                wordCount++;
            }
        }
        return wordCount;
    }
}
```

Comment: Insight into what?

Comment: Please think about accept an answer, this is how a forum works, and a new user would be more attracted from accepted post than non-accepted post

Answer (score 4):

You need to call your method by its `name` and the good `parameters`, in your case :

```
String s = in.nextLine();
System.out.println("There are " + countWords(s) + " words.");
```

A part from that, your method is good, and it's working

---

Tips (just to let you know another way) this will do same :

```
public static int countWords(String str) {
    return str.split("\\s+").length;
}
```

It will split your sentence where there is spaces and create an array (array of words so) and take it's length : number of words

Answer (score 3):

You did not properly call the method:

```
System.out.println("There are " + (countWords) + " words.");
```

should become

```
System.out.println("There are " + countWords(s) + " words.");
```

also, you could also try and do the same thing by splitting the string on spaces and use the length() method on the outputted array. This would make your method a lot less complicated.

See azro's answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Chapter3Question5 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Type some words: ");
String s = in.nextLine();
System.out.println("There are " + countWords(s) + " words.");
//want to call the method here and print the results

in.close();
}
 public static int countWords(String str)
{
 int wordCount = 0;

    boolean word = false;
    int endLine = str.length() - 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {

        if (Character.isLetter(str.charAt(i)) && i != endLine) {
            wordCount++;
            word = true;

        } else if (!Character.isLetter(str.charAt(i)) && word) {
            wordCount++;
            word = false;

        } else if (Character.isLetter(str.charAt(i)) && i == endLine) {
            wordCount++;
        }
    }
    return wordCount;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to call your method properly. It expects parameters and you haven't passed any. Also you have no parentheses on your method call. So it should be:

```
System.out.println("There are " + (countWords(s)) + " words."); // add parentheses and parameters
```

As a side note, that functionality can be implemented easier like this:

```
public class Chapter3Question5 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Type some words: ");
        String s = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("There are " + (countWords(s)) + " words.");
        //want to call the method here and print the results

        in.close();
    }

    public static int countWords(String str) {
        return str == null || str.length() == 0 ? 0 : str.split("\\s+").length;
    }
}
```

Here I'm splitting the string by the spaces, resulting in an array of the words. Next returning the length of the array.

Test and Output:

> Type some words:
>   hola hello  world bye
>   There are 4 words.

Comment: @JaviG please read: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)